# Fill missing values of one column from another column

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VMWO.png)

| PNU | bulid_year | trade_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2015 | 2016 |
| 1234 | 2015 | 2020 |
| 1234 | NaN | 2015 |

If 'PNU' is same, 'bulid_year' is same.
'bulid_year' columns have a missing value according to 'trade_year'.
I want fill 'build_year' missing value with another columns that same 'PNU'.
how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide actual data (instead of a link to an image). Also please give an example of desired output. Also please provide the code you have attempted and why it did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.